# Xorg 1.15 and AMD 13.1 legacy

Tags: ati, xorg

I have a question: Will my ati Radeon 5145(4570) work with ubuntu 14.04? I need proprietary driver for good energy control. I have Laptop.

Or I need to downgrade Xorg?

Comment: Go to this article Your issue would be solve : http://askubuntu.com/questions/450394/amd-catalyst-installation/450402#450402

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution is right here : http://www.thefanclub.co.za/how-to/ubuntu-amd-catalyst-install

Answer (score 0):

I have the same type of graphics card, but I don't have a driver. use s3tc. its a compression tool. start by adding ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa to your ppa list, sudo apt-get update, then go to the software center and look up s3tc and there are 2 packages. install them both, and make sure you run the update manager. I did this, and my computer runs faster and better than ever when playing steam games.
you do not necessarily need one, but if you are a gamer, I recommend this

Comment: s3tc? It is only texture compressing. I need power management.