# AMD Catalyst installation

Tags: 14.04, drivers, graphics, amd-graphics, catalyst

I did a clean install of Ubuntu 14.04 but I can't install Catalyst. When I try to install the driver it displays an error that there is no compatible adapter. I tried it with the stable and the beta driver. Any clues?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, check your graphics card name and chipset:

```
sudo update-pciids #optional command, requires internet
lspci -nn | grep VGA
```

It should report something like this for your graphics card:

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RV710 [Radeon HD 4550]
```

then to check whether your graphics card is fully supported of not check [this page on the Ubuntu help wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RadeonDriver).

> Unsupported Chips
>   For the very latest cards, open-source driver support is not always instant. The following cards require a newer version of the driver than what's found in Ubuntu 13.04/Raring's repository, but should be supported by the time Ubuntu 13.10/Saucy is released.
>
> ```
> OLAND               Radeon HD 8xxx series
> HAINAN              Radeon HD 88xx series
> RICHLAND            Radeon HD 8xxxG series
> ```

I should say that in newer versions of Ubuntu you don't need to install catalyst control center as it's installed by default and if you try to install a catalyst driver 90% of time you would lose your desktop and taskbar and you'd need to purge fglrx and restore the default version of Ubuntu xorg or fgrlx driver.

installing catalyst control center :

run these commands in terminal

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:makson96/fglrx
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic
```

after that open Software Center and type

**legacy catalyst control**
or

click on more and click on amd catalyst legacy .

and install fglrx catalyst control center .

**Removing**:

First go to software & updates and remove **ppa:makson96/fglrx** or try :

```
sudo apt-add-repository --remove ppa:makson96/fglrx
sudo apt-get update
```

Then:

```
sudo sh /usr/share/ati/fglrx-uninstall.sh
sudo apt-get remove --purge fglrx fglrx_* fglrx-amdcccle* fglrx-dev*
```

Note: ignore any errors you may have got form running the first 2 commands.

Remove your xorg.conf file

```
sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

Re-install xorg

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx:amd64 libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64 xserver-xorg-core
```

Configure xorg

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg
```

Reboot:

```
sudo reboot
```

Try this for newer kernel : 
http://www.thefanclub.co.za/how-to/ubuntu-amd-catalyst-install

Comment: My graphics card is unsupported.. Also if I understood correctly, there is no need for me to install catalyst because it is already installed in Ubuntu 14.04?

Comment: yes it's binary version is already installed on Ubuntu . but if your graphic card is unsupported you need to install the catalyst , I have added a way above to install catalyst that won't break but it's 50 -50 chance it work.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to try it now but can you add a way to remove it if it doesn't work?

Comment: I added the repository but when i did the "apt-get update" at the end it displayed that i t failed to fetch and the error "404 not found" for your repository.

Comment: don't mention , I've added a way to remove it .

Comment: It seems there is something wrong with the repository

Comment: I have added a link that may help you with the new kernel.

Answer (score 0):

I have similar problem. And the issue is that catalyst 14 is not compatible with Xorg 1.15. You can check your version of Xorg

```
Xorg -version
```